# Problemas con bucle While en Python

Tags: python, bucles, while

En este ejercicio tengo un problema con la indentacion. No veo el error pero mi editor insiste en que la indentacion está mal. A ver si alguien consigue ver q ocurre:

```
n=int(input("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: "))

for i in range(0,n):
  numero1 = float(input("Ingrese un numero: ")) # 2
  numero2 = float(input(f"Ingrese un numero mayor que \"{int(numero1)}\": "))
  while numero2<numero1:
      print("El numero es menor que \"{}\"!".format(int(numero1)))
    numero2 = float(input(f"Ingrese un numero mayor que \"{int(numero1)}\": "))
  print("Gracias por su cooperacion.", "\n", "Que tenga un buen dia.")
```

Incluso los comentarios debajo de este codigo aparece subrayados como si tuvieran un error, a pesar q están debidamente encerrados entre ''' '''

Comment: en vez de usar `tabular` utiliza 3 espacios es mas fasil... y te ayuda a no tener estos imcobenientes ya que el `tabular` varia mucho dependiendo de la configuracion de cada editor...

Comment: Muchas gracias. Usando el tabulador todo estaba en su lugar, pero por alguna razon no lo aceptaba.

Comment: Si bien no es una obligación, es bueno seguir convenciones y estándares. PEP 8 dice claramente: [Code Lay-out - indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation): Use 4 spaces per indentation level. Y más abajo recomienda los espacios en vez de tabulaciones.

Comment: El problema está la segunda línea del bucle while que solamente tiene 2 espacios de indentación cuando debe tener 4 espacios. La regla de la indentación es que el número de espacios siempre debe ser múltiplos de 4.

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de indentación dentro del `while`:

```
n = int(input("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: "))

for i in range(0, n):
    numero1 = float(input("Ingrese un numero: "))  # 2
    numero2 = float(input(f"Ingrese un numero mayor que \"{int(numero1)}\": "))
    while numero2 < numero1:
        print("El numero es menor que \"{}\"!".format(int(numero1)))
        numero2 = float(input(f"Ingrese un numero mayor que \"{int(numero1)}\": "))
    print("Gracias por su cooperacion.", "\n", "Que tenga un buen dia.")
```

En Python la indentación es crucial; determina el significado del código.